# Принудительная типизация PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, функции, типы-данных, plpgsql

Возникла проблема. Есть такая функция (подсчитывающая общий бюджет, включая отделы ниже):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.DEPT_BUDGET (DNO BPCHAR(3))
RETURNS TABLE (
    TOT DECIMAL(12,2)
)
AS $DEPT_BUDGET$
DECLARE sumb DECIMAL(12, 2);
DECLARE rdno BPCHAR(3)[];
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
DECLARE I BPCHAR(3);
BEGIN
    tot = 0;

    SELECT "BUDGET" FROM department WHERE dept_no = dno INTO tot;

    SELECT count("BUDGET") FROM department WHERE head_dept = dno INTO cnt;

    IF cnt = 0 
    THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT "BUDGET" FROM department WHERE dept_no = dno;
    END IF;
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(dept_no)
    FROM
        department
    WHERE
        head_dept = dno
    INTO
        rdno;
        
    FOREACH I IN ARRAY rdno
    LOOP
        SELECT * FROM DEPT_BUDGET(I) INTO SUMB;
        tot = tot + sumb;
    END LOOP;

END; $DEPT_BUDGET$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

При попытке запустить ее возникает ошибка:

```
SELECT public.dept_budget('000'::VARCHAR);
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function dept_budget(integer) does not exist
  Подсказка: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Если поменять тип входного параметра, чтобы функция в целом запускалась, возникает ошибка следующая:

```
SQL Error [22004]: ERROR: FOREACH expression must not be null
  Где: PL/pgSQL function dept_budget(character) line 25 at FOREACH over array
```

Принудительная типизация

```
WHERE
        head_dept = cast(dno as varchar)
```

не срабатывает, и результат SELECT'а равен NULL. Почитала, что Postgres в принципе автоматически конвертирует char в bpchar, и "лучшее" решение -- не использовать char вовсе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибки, чтобы функция запускалась? Какой тип где поставить?
[image: Типы используемых полей в таблице]

Comment: Хорошо бы приложить типы используемых полей в таблице

Comment: `I` должно иметь тот же тип, что и `dept_no` в базе данных

Comment: Момент с I поправила, собиралась делать циклом FOR и забыла, но проблема не решилась. Прикрепила скриншот типов используемых полей.

Comment: Если в базе `bpchar(3)`, то везде должен быть этот тип: в параметре `dno`, и в локальных переменных `I`, `rdno`.

Comment: Увы, я пробовала все вариации, если оставить везде `bpchar`, то возникает ошибка, что Foreach выдает NULL.

Comment: Возможно, проблема уже не с функцией, а с данными. Например, в `ARRAY_AGG(dept_no)` агрегирует NULL

Comment: Ну и ещё раз советую заменить тело функции рекурсивным запросом

Comment: Плюс рекурсивного запроса - простота отладки. Просто копируешь запрос, ставишь константу в `dno -- Входной параметр`, заменяешь `sum(BUDGET)` на `*`и получаешь все строки, до которых он дотянулся и их данные. С твоей рекурсивной функцией ты затрахаешься с отладкой, если понадобится. Да она тебе, собственно, уже понадобилась.

Answer (score 0):

Твой подход в принципе неправильный - ты используешь Постгрис как императивный язык, а он база данных и у него есть мощные инструменты по обработке данных.

Из того, что я понял, задача такая - посчитать общий бюджет отдела и его подотделов. Для этого надо использовать иерархические запросы

```
with recursive hierarchy(dept_no, head_dept, BUDGET) as (
  select department.dept_no, department.head_dept, department.BUDGET 
  from department 
  where dept_no = dno -- Входной параметр
  
  union all
  
  select department.dept_no, department.head_dept, department.BUDGET 
  from department , hierarchy 
  where department.head_dept = hierarchy.dept_no 
)
select sum(BUDGET) from hierarchy
```

Comment: Нет, мне надо это оформить именно функцией.

Comment: Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы перенести базу данных Employee с Firebird на Postgres, учитывая особенности обеих СУБД. В Employee реализовано несколько процедур, которые я сейчас и пытаюсь переписать. Обычные селективные задачи не представляют интереса.

Comment: А кто мешает этот запрос засунуть в функцию?